# Root finding over finite field extension

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, finite-fields

I'd like to know if there exists any method on Mathematica, third-party coded resource or library that can compute roots of a polynomial over an extension $\mathbb{E}$ where $E=F_p[x]/f(x)$ and $f(x)$ irreducible over $F_p$. For example, you can call **Roots[p[x]==0,x,Modulus->p]** but only works over $F_p$, so roots are just in $\mathbb{Z_p}$.

In literature tipically is referenciated as root finding and methods exists like Berlekamp Trace algorithm and Von Zur Gathen-Shoup algorithm:

Let $K=GF(2), \mathbb{E}=GF(2^n)$

Input: Polynomial $p(x)$ over $\mathbb{E}$ of degree $d$ and a polynomial $y \in \mathbb{E}$ over $K$ such that $p(x)=y$ for unknown $x\in \mathbb{E}$ over $K$.

Otput: The polynomial $x\in E$ that is a solution to the polynomial $r(x)=p(x)-y$ where $r(x) \in F_{q^n}$.

This means that every coefficient found in either $p,r$ belongs to $\mathbb{E}$ and polynomials $x,y \in E$ are polynomials over $F_p$.

How can I proceed in Mathematica? In sage is prety easy.

---

#### Example time in SAGE:

K.< x > = GF(2)[]

E.< a > = GF(2^6,modulus=x^6+x^5+1)

F.< t > = E[]

f = t^4+t^2+1

P=f-f.subs(t=a^2+a+1)

P.roots()

[(a^2 + a, 2), (a^2 + a + 1, 2)]

Recovering $x = a^2+a+1 \in E$. Note that $F$ is a polynomial ring on a single variable $t$ over $E$.

Comment: This question refers both to root-finding and polynomial decomposition. It really needs a concrete example, with copy-able input and the desired output indicated. It is otherwise quite difficult to discern what specifically is wanted.

Comment: Yes I didn't notice it at all. It was missleading but I hope that now clarifies what I'm looking for. Thanks Daniel for your comment (as always).

Comment: Well the question has been solved using NTL on C++ as it offers factoring and root solving of univariate polynomials over finite extension fields. See GF2EX.h and FindRoots method. But the question remains open regarding Mathematica usage, there should be an external resource that I don't know about it.

Comment: In principle this can be done using the characteristic-2 variant of the Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm. But, to my dismay and disappointment, I cannot get it to work. I expect it is a simple bug in my code. I wanted to point out that this is a viable route to take regardless of my own ineptness. Who knows, maybe next week I'll get it right.